# Buffering output with AWK

Tags: awk

I have an input file which consists of three parts:

```
inputFirst
inputMiddle
inputLast
```

Currently I have an AWK script which with this input creates an output file which consists of two parts:

```
outputFirst
outputLast
```

where *outputFirst* and *outputLast* is generated (on the fly) from *inputFirst* and *inputLast* respectively. However, to calculate the *outputMiddle* part (which is only one line) I need to scan the entire input, so I store it in a variable. The problem is that the value of this variable should go in between *outputFirst* and *outputLast* in the output file.

Is there a way to solve this using a single portable AWK script that takes no arguments? Is there a portable way to create temporary files in an AWK script or should I store the output from *outputFirst* and *outputLast* in two variables? I suspect that using variables will be quite inefficient for large files.

Comment: _"Is there a (portable) way to solve this problem?"_  The answer is _yes_.  If you want a more detailed answer, it would help if you provided more details in the question.

Comment: @John1024 Let's say the input is a file of 100 numbers and the output is a file of all numbers incremented by one where the total (sum) is inserted between the 50:th and 51:th number and I want to create this output from a single AWK script. Is there a portable way to create temporary files in AWK?

Comment: It is easy enough to do that.  See answer below.

Comment: What does _"takes no parameters"_ mean?

Comment: @John1024 I mean command line arguments.

Comment: @John1024 I have rewritten the question in a (hopefully) clearer way.

Comment: I think you will find that supplying more context as well as real data and code will dramatically  improve your chances of receiving actually helpful, adequate answers. See the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section for tips and guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output file is not too large (whatever that is), saving *outputLast* in a variable is quite reasonable. The first part, *outputFirst*, can (as described) be generated on the fly. I tried this approach and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of AWK (since at least 1985) can do basic I/O redirection to files or pipelines, just like the shell can, as well as run external commands without I/O redirection.

So, there are any number of ways to approach your problem and solve it without having to read the entire input file into memory.  The most optimal solution will depend on exactly what you're trying to do, and what constraints you must honour.

A simple approach to the more precise example problem you describe in your comment above would perhaps go something like this:  first in the `BEGIN` clause form two unique filenames with `rand()` (and define your variables), then read and sum the first 50 numbers from standard input while also writing them to a temporary file, then continuing to read and sum the next 50 numbers and write them to a second file, then finally in an `END` clause you would use a loop to read the first temporary file with `getline` and write it to standard output, print the total sum, then read the second temporary file the same way and write it to standard output, and finally call `system("rm " file1 " " file2)` to remove the temporary files.

Comment: Adding numbers was just an example to illustrate what the problem could be. In my case the processing is a bit more complicated. However, the output tends to be at most a few hundred lines so reading the it into memory seems quite reasonable after all.

Comment: So, then you're not really asking any question then, are you.

Answer (score 0):

Print the "first" output while processing the file, then write the remainder to a temporary file until you have written the middle.

Here is a self-contained shell script which processes its input files and writes to standard output.

```
#!/bin/sh
t=$(mktemp -t middle.XXXXXXXXX) || exit 127
trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT
trap 'exit 126' HUP INT TERM
awk -v temp="$t" "NR<500000 { print n+1 }
    { s+=$1 }
    NR>=500000 { print n+1 >>temp
    END { print s }' "$@"
cat "$t"
```

For illustration purposes, I used really big line numbers. I'm afraid your question is still too vague to really obtain a less general answer, but perhaps this can help you find the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem with this approach, however, is that it requires a wrapper script for appending the temporary output and deleting the temporary file. It is also not clear how to safely and portably create and delete a temporary file within an AWK script.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm rather flummoxed by your comment. A shell script which contains a snippet of Awk as a helper function is a completely normal and regular thing. If you really require  everything to happen in a  single process, for example, then that's a quite unusual requirement which should definitely be spelled out and explained with a rationale in your question; but then, Awk is a very poor implementation language, and you  should seriously  consider switching to e.g. Python instead.

Comment: In the meantime, I have updated my answer to show you a free-standing shell script which sets up the I/O and then calls Awk for the data processing  The `mktemp` / `trap` idiom is how to securely set up a temp file which is removed when the script is terminated either because it finishes or because it is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: My AWK script is 232 lines, that's why I keep it in a separate file. I also don't like the idea of supplying implementation dependent data (the temporary file in this case) to the awk script. It breaks the abstraction.